# How do I use JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json

When I query a server I get a JSON file in return. The JSON file I get back would be in the following format.

```
{
  "head": {
    "link": [],
    "vars": ["bookName", "author"]
  },
  "results": {
    "distinct": false,
    "ordered": true,
    "bindings": [
      {
        "bookName": {
          "type": "literal",
          "xml:lang": "en",
          "value": "Of Mice and Men"
        },
        "author": {
          "type": "literal",
          "xml:lang": "en",
          "value": "John Steinbeck"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
 $.ajax({ 
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: queryUrl,
    success: function(data) {    
        // get the table element
        var table = $("#results"); 


        // get the sparql variables from the 'head' of the data.
        var headerVars = data.head.vars; 

        // using the vars, make some table headers and add them to the table;
        var trHeaders = getTableHeaders(headerVars);
        table.append(trHeaders);  

        // grab the actual results from the data.                                          
        var bindings = data.results.bindings;

        var book = data.results.bindings[1].bookName.value;

        // for each result, make a table row and add it to the table.
        var numberOfBooks = 0;
        for(rowIdx in bindings){
            table.append(getTableRow(headerVars, bindings[rowIdx]));
            numberOfBooks++;
        }             

        document.getElementById("searched-for").innerHTML="<h1>You seach for " + '"' + input + '"' + " and we found " + numberOfBooks + " books </h1>";
    }
});
```

What I want to be able to do is something like this:

```
var book = data.results.binding[1].bookName.value;
```

Comment: Arrays are zero-indexed so `bindings[1]` selects the *second* element (and there are only one). Is that the problem?

Comment: It's not a JSON, this is javascript object. instead of using `for in` try to use `forEach or map` methods. @JJJ is right you have the only one object in array so it should be [0] instead of [1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({ 
dataType: "jsonp",
url: queryUrl,
success: function(data) {    
    // get the table element
    var table = $("#results"); 


    // get the sparql variables from the 'head' of the data.
    var headerVars = data.head.vars; 

    // using the vars, make some table headers and add them to the table;
    var trHeaders = getTableHeaders(headerVars);
    table.append(trHeaders);  

    // grab the actual results from the data.                                          
    var bindings = data.results.bindings;

    var book;

    if(bindings && bindings.length) {
        book = bindings[0].bookName.value;
    }

    // for each result, make a table row and add it to the table.
    var numberOfBooks = 0;
    for(rowIdx in bindings){
        table.append(getTableRow(headerVars, bindings[rowIdx]));
        numberOfBooks++;
    }             

    document.getElementById("searched-for").innerHTML="<h1>You seach for " + '"' + input + '"' + " and we found " + numberOfBooks + " books </h1>";
}
});
```

But that will only get the first book, if it exists.